# Where is the error in this Jade file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Jade is not an easy language to deal with because of the proper indentation and what not, but in this case indentation does not seem to be the problem and I have Google-Foo'd the error and cannot find one that matches what is going on here.

This is my `addpost.jade` file:

```
extends layout

block content
    h1=title
    ul.errors
        if errors
            each error, i in errors
                li.alert.alert-danger #{error.msg}
    form(method='post', action='/posts/add', enctype="multipart/form-data")
        .form-group
            label Title:
            input.form-control(name='title', type='text')
        .form-group
            label Category
            select.form-control(name='category')
                each category, i in categories
                    option(value='#{category.title}') #{category.title}
        .form-group
            label Body
            textarea.form-control(name='body', id='body')
        .form-group
            label Main Image:
            input.form-control(name='mainimage', type='file')
        .form-group
            label Author
            select.form-control(name='author')
                option(value='Daniel Cortes') Daniel Cortes
                option(value='Alejandra Rocha') Alejandra Rocha
        input.btn.btn-default(name='submit', type='submit', value='Save')
```

And this is the error I am getting:

> addpost.jade:16 14| label Category 15| select.form-control(name='category') > 16| each category, i in categories 17| option(value='#{category.title}') #{category.title} 18| .form-group 19| label Body Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

This is my posts.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var db = require('monk')('localhost/nodeblog');

router.get('/add', function(req, res, next){
    var categories = db.get('categories');

    categories.find({},{},function(err, categories){
        res.render('addpost',{
        "title": "Add Post",
        "categories": categories
        });
    });


});

router.post('/add', function(req, res, next){
    // Get Form Values
    var title       = req.body.title;
    var category    = req.body.category;
    var body        = req.body.body;
    var author      = req.body.author;
    var date        = new Date();

    if(req.files.mainimage){
        var mainImageOriginalName   = req.files.mainimage.originalname;
        var mainImageName           = req.files.mainimage.name;
        var mainImageMime           = req.files.mainimage.mimetype;
        var mainImagePath           = req.files.mainimage.path;
        var mainImageExt            = req.files.mainimage.extension;
        var mainImageSize           = req.files.mainimage.size;
    } else {
        var mainImageName = 'noimage.png';
    }

    // Form Validation
    req.checkBody('title','Title field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('body', 'Body field is required');

    // Check errors
    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors){
        res.render('addpost',{
            "errors": errors,
            "title": title,
            "body": body
        });
    } else {
        var posts = db.get('posts');

        // Submit to db
        posts.insert({
            "title": title,
            "body": body,
            "category": category,
            "date": date,
            "author": author,
            "mainimage": mainimage
        }, function(err, post){
            if(err){
                res.send('There was an issue submitting the post');
            } else {
                req.flash('success','Post Submitted');
                res.location('/');
                res.redirect('/');
            }
        });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

my app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var db = require('monk')('localhost/nodeblog');
var multer = require('multer');
var flash = require('connect-flash');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var posts = require('./routes/posts');

var app = express();

app.locals.moment = require('moment');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// Handle File Uploads & Multipart Data
// app.use(multer({dest: './uploads'}));
app.use(multer({dest:'./uploads/'}).single('singleInputFileName'));

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// Express Session
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true
}));

// Express Validator
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value){
    var namespace = param.split('.'),
    root = namespace.shift(),
    formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Connect Flash
app.use(flash());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});

// Make our db accessible to our router
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  req.db = db;
  next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/posts', posts);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `categories` is not passed to the view or its not a array.

Can you add the code that render the template? May be we can find the problem there.

Comment: Yeiniel, I added the posts.js file, are you suggesting the problem is there?

Comment: yes. it seems you are missing variables needed by the template

Comment: In the case an error presents during form validation the template rendering will fails as the categories variable is not included

Comment: i added var categories = db.get('categories'); in the router.get() as  you can see above, was this not enough?

Comment: Yea i see but `db.get()` do not return an array per [documentation](https://automattic.github.io/monk/) and this is the actual problem: the variable value you are passing to the template is not an array.

Comment: Yeiniel, can you offer a suggestion because I also tried var categories = require('categories') and this has not worked either.

Comment: Yeiniel, I erased that line in the addpost.jade file and then added it again properly indented and then shut off and turned on again via npm start and the error is gone.

Comment: May be you can `console.log(err, categories)` before rendering the template. That way you can check if the callback is not returning an invalid value.

Comment: Still I am having trouble. I am not able to see the category values after I reload the page by not filling all the required fields. Validation message is showing but instead category value is not there.

Comment: you are using the same template on the post method handler and not passing categories there. May be thats the problem?

Comment: @yeiniel Can you please write the code here for better understanind, since i a new to node js.